# What is the use case of reference type in Firestore Document and how to use it specially in an android app?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

In my Android app, if I get the document path by getting the value of reference type field of a document then how am I going to call it? Because the reference path I'm going to get would be something like `/Users/OctUsers/1stWeekUsers/OlCvJFfWZeAlcttdlgzz/` and method for retrieving a Firestore document is something like 
`FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(collectionPath).document(documentPath).collection(collectionPath).document(documentPath)` and so on. How am I going to iterate over reference path for getting every collectionPath and documentPath to be used in the Firestore DocumentReferece#get method?

Has anyone actually used this reference field type in their Firestore database then please drop the screenshot for letting us know more use cases of this?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are storing the following document reference in the database:

```
/Users/OctUsers/1stWeekUsers/OlCvJFfWZeAlcttdlgzz/
```

And you want to get this:

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(collectionPath).document(documentPath).collection(collectionPath).document(documentPath)
```

You can symply rewrite it like this:

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().document("/Users/OctUsers/1stWeekUsers/OlCvJFfWZeAlcttdlgzz/");
```

Remember, the most important part in a `DocumenetReference` object is the string path. If you want to get that String representation, use DocumentReference's [getPath()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference.html#getPath()) method for that.

Furthermore, if you need to deserialize that path String back into a `DocumentReference` object, simply use [FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().document(path)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestore.html#document(java.lang.String)).

Comment: Oh so writing string path with slashes like Realtime Database is also allowed in Firestore. I didn't know that. Thanks. Upvoting and will accept the answer if no better answer appears by tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

When you query for a document contains a reference type field, the field will show up in a DocumentSnapshot on an Android client as a DocumentReference type object.  You can treat this just like any other DocumentReference that you build on your own.  You can call `get()` on it to get the referred document a you would normally.  You don't have to do anything to parse the path to the document (unless you want to).